# Remove first slide in bxSlider onSliderAfter without breaking it

Tags: bxslider

I would like to use bxSlider to make a slider but that the first slide on appears once. It's just an intro slide that would be remove after the next is loaded.

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li class="one"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried something like

```
    $('#slider ul').bxSlider({
        pager: false,
        auto: true,
        onSlideAfter : function(){
            $('#slider ul li.one').remove();
        }
    });
```

But this crashed the slider probably before the width of the slider is not equal to it's initial width now that one slide has been removed. Any clue on how I should make it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search and testing this come up

```
var topSlider = $('#slider ul').bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    auto: true,
    onSlideAfter : function(){
        if($('#slider ul li.one').length >= 1){
            $('#slider ul li.one').remove();
            topSlider.reloadSlider();
        }
    }
});
```

So when the second slide is done, I check if the first slide still exist, if so, I remove it and reload the slider without it. Seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of removing it, in `onSlideBefore` you check if you are going to the first slide and if you are send it immediately to the second?

```
$('#slider ul').bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    auto: true,
    onSlideBefore : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
      if(newIndex == 0){
        $('#slider ul').bxSlider.goToSlide(1);
      }
    }
});
```

I am not sure how bxslider will react, i.e. will you slide past the first slide on the way to the second slide.  If that is the case, then this probably will not work.